# tf, translation between frames

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a setup with multiple target frames. Now I want to get the position of my last frame in relation to the world frame.
During execution typing

**rosrun tf tf_echo /world /LAST_LINK**

I receive exactly what I am looking for

**- Translation: [20.632, 0.000, -3.759]

- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.574, -0.000, 0.819, 0.000]
  in RPY [-0.000, 1.222, 3.142]**

How can I read these values in my program in order to perform further calculations from it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199154/tf,-translation-between-frames/) by [psfa_fz](https://answers.ros.org/users/20415/psfa_fz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read the [TF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This information should be located in the `/tf` topic. What I used to select the header frame and child frame is:

- subscribe to the `/tf` topic, your callback function will get a message of the type `tf::tfMessageConstPtr` let's call this message **msg_in**
- msg_in will have information such as (See [tfMessage.msg](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/msg/tfMessage.html)):
- geometry_msgs/TransformStamped transforms

  - std_msgs/Header header
  - string child_frame_id
  - geometry_msgs/Transform transform

    - geometry_msgs/Vector3 translation
    - geometry_msgs/Quaternion rotation

You are interested in the translation and rotation components so you can access them with:

- msg_in ->transforms[i].transform.rotation.(x, y, z, or w)
- msg_in ->transforms[i].transform.translation(x, y, or z)

Where `i` is the number of the transform message. You can store them in a `tf::Quaternion` and a `tf::Vector3` respectively. Here is a portion of an algorithm that can help you:

```
#include "tf/tf.h"
#include "tf/tfMessage.h"
```

---

```
void tfCB(const tf::tfMessageConstPtr msg)
{
  //Go through all the tf frame information and select the one you are interested in
  for(int i=0; i < msg->transforms.size();i++){
    if (msg->transforms[i].child_frame_id == "/name_of_your_child_frame"){
      cout << "Msg Size: " << msg->transforms.size() << endl;
      cout << "Header Frame: " << msg->transforms[i].header.frame_id << endl;
      cout << "Child Frame: " << msg->transforms[i].child_frame_id << endl;
      cout << "Transform: " << endl << msg->transforms[i].transform << endl;
      cout << "Vector3: " << endl << msg->transforms[i].transform.translation << endl;
      cout << "Quaternion: " << endl << msg->transforms[i].transform.rotation << endl;

      tf::Matrix3x3 Rotation;
      Rotation.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(msg->transforms[i].transform.rotation.x,
         msg->transforms[i].transform.rotation.y, msg->transforms[i].transform.rotation.z, 
         msg->transforms[i].transform.rotation.w));                                   
            
      tf::Vector3 traslation;
      traslation = tf::Vector3(msg->transforms[i].transform.translation.x, 
        msg->transforms[i].transform.translation.y, 
        msg->transforms[i].transform.translation.z);
            
      double roll, pitch, yaw;
      Rotation.getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll); 
        
      tf::Matrix3x3 RotationYPR;
      RotationYPR.setEulerYPR(yaw,pitch,roll);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
sub_tf = nh_.subscribe("/tf",100,&Marker_info::tfCB, this); //the call back function belongs to a struct called Marker_info. The idea is to show you the subscriber. You can change this to fit your code.
```

As you can see, you will store the rotation and translation information in a matrix and a vector that complies with the tf format. You can convert them using tools like `tf::VectorTFToEigen`.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) with karma: 182 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-12**:
You should almost never directly subscribe to TF messages. This is what a TFListener is for. You don't want to look for your transformations manually.